# Query regarding individual polarization calculation using CP2K

Tags: molecular-modeling, ab-initio-calculations, cp2k, aimd

I am seeking assistance in calculating the individual polarization matrix from CP2K. While utilizing the Polar input under FORCE_EVAL -> PROPERTIES -> LINRES -> POLAR, I observed that the output provides the bulk polarization of the entire system but I want to know how to obtain the individual polarization matrix through CP2K.

Any help is greatly appreciated.